# R equivalent of GRASS r.grow?

Tags: raster, grass-gis, r

What is a good R equivalent of the GRASS function r.grow?

The closest I've been able to find is the script suggested by whuber in response to [Creating randomly shaped clumps of cells in a raster from seeds of 1 cell/pixel?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/60562/creating-randomly-shaped-clumps-of-cells-in-a-raster-from-seeds-of-1-cell-pixel), which is written to address a different problem, so I'd like to know whether there are more efficient tools to simply grow outward uniformly.

Comment: Have you solved this? I have a feeling that you could use focal{raster} to do this... I'll give it some more thought.

Comment: Still haven't solved this.  Best I can come up with so far is to somehow modify the code I linked to to remove randomness (not yet implemented, but seems doable).

Answer (score 1):

There is a workflow to fill in NA values by the nearest non-NA value in R [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37392542/3752258). You can easily set a maximum distance (in map units/meters).